# No clue about a term

Tags: electrostatics, integration, vector-fields, calculus

[image]$\int_S\int \vec{A}\cdot\hat{n}dS= \int_S\int A cos(\theta)dS= \int_S\int \left(A_xdS_x+ A_ydS_y+ A_zdS_z\right)$

---

I have no clue about the term $$\int_S\int \left(A_xdS_x+ A_ydS_y+ A_zdS_z\right)$$

How is that term is generated.
Please clarify.

Comment: I'd be helpful if you could clarify your question, in particular, let us know any research effort of yours, for example, what did you try to prove the above equation? What is meant by $dS_x, dS_y, dS_z$ (I've never before seen that notation)? etc. Do you understand the first equation? (Looks kinda dubious to me...). I suppose you are given a surface integral which is written in carthesian coordinates(?).

Comment: Context is needed.

Comment: I dont understand $dS_x,dS_y,dS_z$

Comment: ds is a small are element here

Comment: @user190081 I added the pic of the topic "surface integrals"

Comment: @Akash Thanks for the context. If you dont find your answer here, you may want to try at: https://math.stackexchange.com. Also, regarding formatting, take this post in consideration:https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10573/197798

Comment: Please don't post cell phone pictures of text. It doesn't work with search engines and it's not accessible to blind people. Please don't cut and paste random stuff on the internet without attribution. It's rude.

Comment: Okay..i will not do that next time

Comment: @BenCrowell why it is problematic for blind People

Comment: @Akash Several blind people use screen-reader programs, which aren't able to read off pictures.

Comment: Okay.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you took the dot product of two vectors, $A$ and $dS$. When we dot two vectors, we multiply the corresponding components and add them. That's how you get the term.

Comment: okay we get corresponding components...would you explain it more

Comment: @Akash please be more specific. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: It looks like we are taking S integral along x-axis,y-axis and z-axis (as you said we take corresponding components while opening a dot product,yeah i know)..it looks unfamiliar to me

Comment: @Akash basically what you do in a dot product is that you obtain the product of magnitude of one vector and the  projection of other vector in the direction of first vector.